# Make bevel sharper

Tags: bevel

I think many have encountered this problem. Usually the bevel becomes round when it is used. Like here, for example
[image]

[image]

However, when you use the bevel on more elongated objects, it becomes oval. How to make it round?
[image]

Comment: You probably need to apply the scale in Object mode

Comment: @moonboots i love u

Comment: Everyone does! :D